# Using Laravel How can get a specific sizes products for a category?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have category migration like this:

```
id
title
parent_id
```

Then I store products in another migration table like this

```
id
category_id
title
price
```

Then I store products in another migration table stocks like this:

```
id
product_id
size (like M/L/1 Year etc)
qty
```

I can get all category products using following query:

```
$category = Category::first();
$products = $category->products;
```

My question is how Can get a specific sizes products? like I want to get all M Sizes Products of a single category?

**Updated Answer:**

```
$category = Category::first();
$products = $category->products()
                     ->whereHas('stocks', function($q){
                          $q->where('size', '=', 'M');
                      })
                     ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do,

```
$category = Category::first();
$products = $category->products()
                     ->whereHas('stocks', function($q){
                          $q->where('size', '=', 'M');
                      })
                     ->get();
```

Comment: This will gives product of first category and i think he need all the categories with product which has particular size.

Comment: @PrateikDarji Thank you. He said, I want to get all M Sizes Products of a single category. Or may be i don't understand him correctly.

Comment: Yes true. My mistake sorry :-)

Comment: Stock is Stored in another table called stocks with a foreign key relationship with product_id

Comment: @Md. Sukel Ali Thanks, Following query solve my problems

`$category = Category::first();
$products = $category->products()
    ->whereHas('stocks', function($q){
         $q->where('size', '=', 'M');
     })
    ->get();`

You can update your answer.

Comment: @UttaraInfoTech udpated

Answer (score 1):

First you get all the categories.

```
$category = Category::first(); // You can get all the categories or in where condition whatever your need
$size = "M" //Comming from the request
```

For products where has categories and size as mentioned
I hope you have relation defined for stock in product model.

```
$product = $category->whereHas('products', function($query) use ($size){
    return $query->whereHas('stock', function($stock) use ($size){
        return $stock->where('size', $size);
    });
})->with(['products'=>function($q) use ($size){
    return $q->whereHas('stock', function($stock) use ($size) {
        return $stock->where('size', $size);
    });
}])->get();
```

This will gives you category which are only having products which has size provided in the request.

Comment: Stock is Stored in another table called stocks with a foreign key relationship with product_id

Comment: How I get all products for a single category? Since your query reterning all category?

Comment: you can use `Category::first()` instead of `Category::all()` @UttaraInfoTech I have updated my answer